# How to get the data from service using aws javascript sdk in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services

I have the data in server but I want to get that using aws javascript sdk in react redux am new to react can any one help me clearly

Comment: In react environment, we use fetch or axios or similary library to request api's(AWS or java api) to perform CRUD operations. Please add your code, where you are facing issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js)

Install it in your react project

```
npm install aws-sdk
```

Import the SDK

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk";
```

And use the AWS services in your js files.

```
const cloudwatch = new AWS.CloudWatch(config);
const storage = new AWS.S3(config);
```

Comment: I added my full Code above please help me